# Can GoogleCast Receiver app read UDP messages without a sender app?

Tags: google-cast

I have an existing app which broadcasts UDP packets containing text.

Is it possible to write a GoogleCast Receiver app which will listen for these messages (from specific IP address and port) and display them on the TV?

Because I already have the software (VB) to broadcast the packets, I don't really want to have to write a sender app

Comment: No, you need to write a new sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sender app doesn't broadcast anything; the sender app just communicates with the Chromecast to instruct it how to load the receiver and to pass any instructions from the viewer. So you'll still need to write both ... the sender will be sort of the remote control (to at least get the communication started), and the receiver will be the consumer of the UDP packets that the Chromecast displays.